# Cyclic dependency analysis for Java 8 - for use in an automated build

Tags: java-8, jdepend, cyclic-dependency

I'll working on a project that is using JDepend to automatically generate a report of cyclic package dependencies as part of our CI build.  (I am mainly interested in package level dependencies, so I've been using a cut down version of the XSLT to get a more focused report - otherwise, though, it is vanilla JDepend.)

However we are about to move the project to Java 8 and I have found that JDepend does not work against code compiled with the JDK 1.8 compiler.  JDepend no longer seems to be being actively updated.

I'm trying to find a replacement that:

- Works with JDK 1.8 compiled class and/or jars.
- Reports cyclic dependencies at the package and/or jar level.
- Can be automated from Ant (command line executable would do).
- Produces a report that can be linked from a project home page and opened in a browser (e.g. HTML or plain text output - not a desktop app).
- Also (preferably) produces - or can be configured/tweaked to produce - a focused report of just the cyclic dependencies (as JDepend can, if you modify the XSLT).

Comment: Okay, so... I completely missed the fact that this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdeps.html - exists in the JDK 1.8 tool set.  (Just trying it now.)

Comment: would love a tool for maven that could also fail the build...

Comment: Yes, I like a simple tool to fail the build (or maybe a unit test) if there are any cyclic dependencies between packages and/or jars, too.

Comment: You might be able to write a unit test that compares the current output of jdeps.exe to some earlier version that represented acceptable dependencies.  If the dependencies change the test will fail - at which point you either fix the dependencies or update the test to reflect that the new dependencies are still acceptable.  (Bit of a hack, but...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 includes `jdeps.exe` in the `/bin`.  Although this doesn't *explicitly* call out cyclic dependencies it does show all dependencies for a project's packages.  It's good enough.